# Вывод на сайте кастомных полей через админку Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Задача сделать возможность добавления из админки информации следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как реализовать добавление данных (картинок, текста) в эти блоки из админки?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - плагин [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). Есть плагины-аналоги: Carbon Fields, Meta Box. Можно и самому создать метабоксы, в WordPress [есть механизм](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box) для этого.